# Creating custom checkout gateway for magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I need to create a custom payment gateway for Magento.

Please give me a starting point guide to do that.

Thanks

Comment: start with <?php .. -- how do you expect this question to be answered?

Comment: @Dagon: I need a starting point guide for magento, Not PHP help.

Comment: the magento website has a huge amount of help.

Answer (score 1):

try the following link

[Creating Your Own Payment Gateway For Magento](http://roysimkes.net/blog/tag/magento/)